How to generate jOOQ POJO classes programmatically before running Spring Boot application?
I am using the following code to generate POJO and record classes from my database using jOOQ:
@Component
public class JooqCodeGenerator implements CommandLineRunner {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JooqCodeGenerator.class);

  @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
  private String url;

  @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
  private String username;

  @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
  private String password;

  @Value("${jooq.generator.database.inputSchema}")
  private String inputSchema;

  @Value("${jooq.generator.target.packageName}")
  private String packageName;

  @Value("${jooq.generator.target.directory}")
  private String directory;

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Starting jOOQ code generation...");
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
        .withJdbc(new Jdbc()
            .withDriver("org.postgresql.Driver")
            .withUrl(url)
            .withUser(username)
            .withPassword(password))
        .withGenerator(new Generator()
            .withDatabase(new Database()
                .withInputSchema(inputSchema)
                .withIncludes(".*")  // Include all tables
                .withExcludes("flyway_schema_history|pg_*"))  // Exclude Flyway and default PostgreSQL tables
            .withTarget(new Target()
                .withPackageName(packageName)
                .withDirectory(directory))
            .withGenerate(new Generate()
                .withDaos(true)
                .withPojos(true)
                .withInterfaces(false)
                .withImmutablePojos(false)
                .withFluentSetters(true)
                .withJavaTimeTypes(true)));

    GenerationTool.generate(configuration);

    logger.info("jOOQ code generation completed.");
  }
}

I use these generated classes in my service and controller classes. The issue arises when I run mvn spring-boot:run. I encounter compilation errors because the POJO classes cannot be found.
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project control: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] ProjectPath/rest/AuditTrailController.java:[3,54] package projectPath.jooq.tables.pojos does not exist

How can I make Spring Boot generate these classes programmatically before running the application? I prefer not to use the Maven plugin for this purpose. Any advice or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!

"I prefer not to use the Maven plugin for this purpose" - Why not?

Not sure about Spring Boot, but I would add Application another entry point. The way I've done it is to wrap the entry points within a class that are linked to start method for example. class Application and methods runCodeGenerators, runMigrations, runApplication. The drawback is that they won't be available in DI
